# Update entry(ies) in Oracle table using temporary column 

Tags: sql, oracle

How can I update the a.age and b.age to 32 for all the results obtained by the below query.the temp column is "CID" as shown in below example

```
select * 
  from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_NAME ORDER BY CUST_NAME) AS CID,CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB 
          FROM (select CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB
                  from SOMETABLE 
                 where date = '26-jULY-2012'))a 
  RIGHT join (select * 
                from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                             OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_NAME ORDER BY CUST_NAME) AS CID,CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB 
                       FROM (select CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB
                               from SOMETABLE2 
                              where date = '26-jULY-2012')))b 
         on a.CID=b.CID 
   and a.CUST_NAME=b.CUST_NAME  
 ORDER BY a.CUST_NAME,A.CID,a.COLUMNB;
```

Comment: _Where_ do you want to update them?

Comment: in the same table where they are retrieved from (e.g.:a.age comes from SOMETABLE)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
update sometable
set age = 32
where cid in (
select a.cid
  from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_NAME ORDER BY CUST_NAME) AS CID,CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB 
          FROM (select CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB
                  from SOMETABLE 
                 where date = '26-jULY-2012'))a 
  RIGHT join (select * 
                from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                             OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_NAME ORDER BY CUST_NAME) AS CID,CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB 
                       FROM (select CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB
                               from SOMETABLE2 
                              where date = '26-jULY-2012')))b 
         on a.CID=b.CID 
   and a.CUST_NAME=b.CUST_NAME  
)
;




update sometable2
set age = 32
where cid in (
select b.cid
  from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
               OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_NAME ORDER BY CUST_NAME) AS CID,CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB 
          FROM (select CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB
                  from SOMETABLE 
                 where date = '26-jULY-2012'))a 
  RIGHT join (select * 
                from (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
                             OVER (PARTITION BY CUST_NAME ORDER BY CUST_NAME) AS CID,CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB 
                       FROM (select CUST_NAME,AGE,CITY,COLUMNB
                               from SOMETABLE2 
                              where date = '26-jULY-2012')))b 
         on a.CID=b.CID 
   and a.CUST_NAME=b.CUST_NAME  
)
;
```

Comment: @schurik-CID is a temporary column which does not exist in SOMETABLE or SOMETABLE2, so your solution will not work

Comment: @HaranMurthy what are the primary keys of the sometable and sometable2?